# Several lists in the same page

Tags: list, list-form

So I have the following lists:

```
Facture: ID (Text), Date (Date)
Ligne_Facture: ID_Facture (Lookup pointing to the ID of the list Facture), ID_Produit (Another lookup), Number (Number), total price (Number).
```

So what I want is to have a page containing the following style of forms: the field ID on the top refering to the ID of the list "Facture" and a grid to fill the list "Ligne_Facture" (the field ID_Facture is automatically the one I just filled and the others are filled manually). Once I save I fill the two Lists. Since I'm a total newbie I wanted to ask you about the right procedures to do so. Thanks in advance, i really appreciate any intervention.

Answer (score 0):

It could be quite difficult to implement the required behavior.

The slightly different approach is to use related lists feature. See, for example, here

[Discription of related lists](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=74&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0)

You can use this approach to modify the display form of Facture list. This should solve the problem with views but still need to write code for creating of related Ligne_Facture records.

As a result you get linked lists but creation should still require multiply steps to create connected records.

The behavior you prefer could only be achieved with custom development or using InfoPath forms